# Populate an array with templated function pointers using a loop?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated function that creates a unique static function to route a callback to various instances (workaround for an old C API with global state).

```
class CallbackObject
{
   // callback state storage
   ...

public:
   void callback(...){ ... };
} _slots[SlotCount];

template<size_t slot>
static void callback(...)
{
   _slots[slot].callback(...);
}

auto _callbacks[SlotCount] =
{
  callback<0>,
  callback<1>,
  ...
  callback<SlotCount-1>
}
```

is there a way to populate the _callbacks array using a loop or other mechanism (each callback object has a set of four different callbacks so it's something I would prefer to avoid doing by hand)?

Comment: `_slots` and `_callbacks` are reserved identifiers in the global namespace. Make sure to not declare them there.

Comment: thanks for the heads up, everything is compartmentalized in my own namespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you switch to using a `std::array`, you can write a function to do this for leveraging a variadic template.  This first function takes a `std::integer_sequence` and uses it to create a parameter pack of `std::size_t` objects that will have the values of the range `[0, size_provided)`

```
template <std::size_t... Is>
auto make_callback_array_helper(std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, Is...>)
{
    return std::array{callback<Is>...};
}
```

This next function is the fucntion that you will call and it dispatches to the first function.  This is useful as the first function has a verbose call syntax.

```
template <std::size_t N>
auto make_callback_array()
{
    return make_callback_array_helper(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

and then you would use it like

```
auto _callbacks = make_callback_array<SlotCount>();
```

Comment: You don't actually need a function or an std::array (though std::array is preferred), see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Ka3x3MEMh).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Neat.  You should add an answer with that in case there are people out there that can't switch to `std::array` for whatever reason.

Comment: my template foo is very rudimentary so it's going to take me a while to pick through this, at the moment though the compiler is not happy with make_callback_array_helper() complaining that the argument list for std::array is missing.

Comment: @norlesh What version of C++ are you using?

Comment: visual studio 2019 - currently set to C++/14 standard

Comment: @norlesh Aha.  This is using a C++17 feature called CTAD which allows the compiler to deduce the type of the `std::array`.  If you are using C++14, you'd need something like `return std::array<type_of_the_callback_function, sizeof...(Is)>{callback<Is>...};`

Comment: just moved up to C++17 and your code working fine.

Comment: @norlesh Awesome.  Glad we got that settled :)